Getting value from Props before making API call
Hey so I'm trying to take a user's latitude and longitude and use that data in an API call to get accurate information.
I'm running into a problem where my API call is being sent before the State that includes the latitude and longitude are being updated. That means the api call is being sent with
`lat=undefined&long=undefined`

rather then
`lat=${latitude}$long=${longitude}`

I'm looking for a way to stop the useEffect from firing until the state is updated.
The state is being passed down as a prop from App.js
 function App() {

  let [latitude, setLatitude] = useState();
  let [longitude, setLongitude] = useState();

   let setLocation = () => {
      if("geolocation" in navigator) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
            setLatitude(e.coords.latitude.toFixed(3))
            setLongitude(e.coords.longitude.toFixed(3))
         })
       } else {
          setLatitude(-34)
          setLongitude(174)
        }
  }
  setLocation();
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header location={{latitude, longitude}}/>
        <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}


To Header.js
const Header = ({location}) => {

    let [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(location.latitude);
    let [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(location.longitude);
    let [cityName, setCityName] = useState('nyet');


     useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://us1.locationiq.com/v1/reverse?key=<apikey>&lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&format=json`)
        .then((res) => {
            if('city' in res.data.address) {
                setCityName(res.data.address.city)
            } else if('county' in res.data.address) {
                setCityName(res.data.address.county)
            } else if('state' in res.data.address) {
                setCityName(res.data.address.state)
            } else if('country' in res.data.address) {
                setCityName(res.data.address.country)
            } else (
                setCityName('')
            )
            })
        .catch((err) => 
            console.log(err)
            )
    }, [latitude, longitude])


    return(
        <>
            <h1>{cityName} Weather</h1>
        </>
    )
}

This is where I'm at now,
I've tried a couple other things but haven't been able to implement them properly, so hopefully someone here can help :)
Thanks in advance!
I've tried implementing a Promise or Async, but I'm just not sure how to properly do it with useEffect, etc.

Use conditional rendering to only display the <Header /> element once you have the appropriate data. You should also run setLocation() in an effect hook
